# strace: ld-linux fails to run a simple test binary

Tags: c, embedded-linux, strace

I am trying to compile some stuff for an embedded system that I'm trying to build upon. However, when running binaries I've built for the system I am met with `failed to map segment from shared object: Invalid argument`. This happens to anything that does more than simple loops and prints.

In the name of debugging this, I've built a binary (testbin) that simply lists the contents of the current directory:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

As the system is somewhat uncooperative in terms of libraries, I have to override it all, so I run programs this way: `./ld-linux.so.3 ./testbin` which produces:

```
./testbin: error while loading shared libraries: ./shitls: failed to map segment from shared object: Invalid argument
```

...as suspected, `testbin` also struggles as soon as external libraries are needed. I managed to statically compile `strace` for the system, which somehow runs just fine. So I'm fairly sure that the culprit is whenever `libc.so` is needed.

When running `strace` on my `testbin` via `ld-linux.so.3` like this: `./strace ./ld-linux.so.3 ./testbin`

..I am presented with something to work with:

```
execve("./ld-linux.so.3", ["./ld-linux.so.3", "./testbin"], 0xbee2b554 /* 74 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xb873c000
open("./testbin", O_RDONLY)             = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0(\0\1\0\0\0\311\203\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1920, SEEK_SET)                = 1920
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1240) = 1240
lseek(3, 1601, SEEK_SET)                = 1601
read(3, "A2\0\0\0aeabi\0\1(\0\0\0\0057-A\0\6\n\7A\10\1\t\2\n\4\22"..., 51) = 51
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=5379, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/mnt/output", 128)    = 22
mmap2(0x5241ae00, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
close(3)                                = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="./testbin", iov_len=9}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libra"..., iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="./testbin", iov_len=9}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="failed to map segment from share"..., iov_len=40}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="Invalid argument", iov_len=16}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10./testbin: error while loading shared libraries: ./testbin: failed to map segment from shared object: Invalid argument
) = 119
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

...but I'm not fluent in reading strace output. Any pointer as to where the running of the binary croaks?

Comment: From the `mmap` man page: "EINVAL (Various platforms where the page size is not 4096 bytes.)  offset * 4096 is not a multiple of the system page size."

Comment: @o11c It is worth noting that I'm not 100% sure of the target architecture. It's some form of ARM compatible Hisilicon chip. Would this mean that I have the compile target wrong? I'm compiling these binaries in a qemu environment based on a best effort setup.

Comment: Since `MAP_FIXED` was specified, the `mmap2` call is probably failing because the address `0x5241ae00` is not page-aligned.

Comment: Note: it hasn't got as far as trying to load `libc.so` yet. The `./ld-linux.so.3` is failing during the mapping of a "text" section (as indicated by the `PROT_EXEC` flag) in the `./testbin` file.

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried to `patchelf` the binary with the correct libc.so, but with no luck. However, the PROT_EXEC strikes me as relevant as I've also been getting "permission denied" when trying various other approaches (I cannot remember exactly which approach produced this, though), as if something is something outside of the usual permissions is keeping me from running the file. Any pointers as to where I can find more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your development sysroot is not matching the sysroot libs on the target. One option is to locate the proper cross-development tools for your chip. Another option is to pull the rootfs from the target and try to build against it inside your qemu setup. For example:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/rootfs-mipsel/mipsel-linux-gnu -lusb-1.0 -ludev
```

Also, the cross-compiler can take the desired rootfs as argument: `--sysroot=/opt/rootfs-mipsel`.

Your current development tools inside qemu may use a different ld.so version than that of the target. After compilation it can be edited with patchelf:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld.so.1 a.out
```